# How to install ROracle on Linux

Tags: oracle

I am trying to install the ROracle library. This fails:

```
install.packages("/storage/Downloads/ROracle_1.1-11.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

** package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: error: OCI libraries not found
```

I have downloaded the Oracle Instantclient RPMs and installed them via alien. Then,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
R CMD INSTALL ROracle_1.1-11.tar.gz

Warning: invalid package ‘ROracle_1.1-11.tar.gz
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
```

How can I install the ROracle package on a Ubuntu 64 system?

Comment: After trying out several [many] options, I think this is more related to Oracle than to the package ROracle. Propose to migrate to "Database Administrators".

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
  --with-oci-inc=/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64'  ROracle_1.1-11.tar.gz
```

Comment: For Oracle instantclient 12.2.0.1.0, I needed to download the sdk and then set `--with-oci-inc=/[instantclient]/sdk/include`

Comment: Finally, I got that!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had it the same and after I checked that the Java SDK is installed (javac -version) I have executed:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client/instantclient/"; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client/lib --with-oci-inc=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client/rdbms/public'  /home/xxx/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz
```